# Binary Search - Deferred Equality check

Tags: c

http://ideone.com/RT84T6

```
while (first <= last) {
    // Assert: Array is sorted and first <= last
    //Initialization:target is within (extremes inclusive) the range of first     and last. IE First<=x<=Last
    mid = (first + last) / 2;

    //Maintenance: Increasing first to mid+1 if x>mid or decrease last to     min-1 if x<mid.
    if (target < arr[mid])
        last = mid - 1;
    else
        first = mid + 1;
}

//Termination: target is not within the array.
return -1;

if ((first <= target) && (arr[first]==target))
    return 1;
else
    return -1;
```

I'm getting an output of -1 each time I run my binary search (Deferred detection of equality version).

I'm having trouble figuring out where it is that its resulting in a -1.

Comment: put `if(arr[mid]==target) return 1;` into while-loop.

Comment: There are a few problems here.  First, consider what happens if `arr[mid]` is equal to `target`.  In that case, you are setting `first` to `mid+1`, i.e. you're moving `first` past the location of `target`.  Second, at the end you're comparing `first`, which is an array index, to `target`, which is an array value.  That clearly doesn't work.

Comment: blue, I want it to strictly have 2 comparisons in the while loop. 

@TomKarzes Ah, thank you! Its getting late where I am and my brains losing its ability to reason :P
I made these changes, hopefully it works!


    while ((first <= last) && (arr[mid]!=target))


     if ((first==last) && (arr[first]==target)) return 1;
 else return -1;

Comment: Also, the first `while` loop should be `while (first < last)`. If they're equal, then you're done.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, you're right. Honestly wish I could grab some coffee right now :( stupid mistakes

Comment: You also have an unconditional `return -1` right after the loop.  So no matter what the loop does, you will return -1.

Comment: Im receiving a segmenation fault now - http://ideone.com/RT84T6

dammit! Aye @TomKarzes I just noticed that too a few minutes ago. Made me go "Hey what are you doing there little buddy? Out. Now." 

:P Also I appreciate your guys' help on this!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: The deferred equality check makes the code decidedly trickier.  When the desired value if found, you don't want to move first/last past it, but on the other hand you can't leave them unchanged or you will go into an infinite loop.

Comment: @TomKarzes 

Yea I've noticed that, is there a work around? and thanks bluepixy I'll have a quick look through that wiki for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete solution, including a simple test driver:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//
// Returns the array index if target is present.
// Returns -1 if target is absent.
//
int bin_search(int *arr, int len, int target)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = len - 1;
    int mid;

    while (first < last) {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;
        // Note:  We require mid < last  for this to work.  This should be
        // the case since integer division uses "truncation towards zero".

        if (arr[mid] < target) {
            first = mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            last = mid;
        }
    }

    if (first == last && arr[first] == target) {
        return first;
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    static int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int ix;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        ix = bin_search(a, 5, i);
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, ix);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0: -1
1: 0
2: 1
3: 2
4: 3
5: 4
6: -1
```

Note that I inverted the in-loop test so that `last` gets updated rather than `first` in the case where `target` has been found.  That guarantees that `last` decreases in that case.  The original could also be made to work, but would require the divide-by-two when setting mid to round up rather than down.

I also changed `bin_search` to return the index of target if present, and -1 if absent.

Comment: This solution brought a tear to my eye.  thanks Tom!